# с какого момента считается таймаут при установке expire в редисе?

Tags: redis, timeout

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые знатоки! Подскажите пожалуйста, с какого момента начинает считаться таймаут при использовании expire? С вызова этого экспайра, или с момента создания ключа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно это зависит от версии redis, но для предпоследней стабильной версии redis-2.6.8(2.6.9 вышел 3 дня назад) наблюдается следующее:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set test 1
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ttl test
(integer) -1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> expire test 300
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ttl test
(integer) 298
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set test 2
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ttl test
(integer) -1
```

Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что команда **SET** делает ключ неистекаемым(персистентным). Если затем будет вызван **EXPIRE**, то действительно можно подумать, что время отсчитывается от установки ключа. 
На самом деле этот эффект появляется при совместном использовании нескольких команд Redis.

SET на самом деле ничего не знает о истечении жизни ключа, а управление временем жизни ключей осуществляется набором команд *EXPIRE, EXPIREAT, TTL, PERSIST*, а  *SET, GETSET, DEL* удаляют старый ключ, и могут создать новый персистентный. Также в 2.6 ветке появились команды *PEXIRE, PEXPIREAT, PTTL*, которые позволяют управлять временем жизни ключей с точностью до миллисекунды.

См. также [пруф1](http://redis.io/commands/expire), [пруф2](http://redis.io/commands) для проверки всего того, что я написал.

Answer (score 0):

C момента вызова expire. При повторном вызове (если таймаут уже установлен), он заменяется на новое значение.

Comment: а вот тут пишут наоборот - с момента установки ключа: http://codemehanika.org/blog/2011-07-15-redis-types-usage.html